# Array of functions with additional arguments in the express router middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, middleware

```
const cb0 = function (data, req, res, next) {
  console.log('CB0')
  next()
}

const cb1 = function (data, req, res, next) {
  console.log('CB1')
  next()
}

app.get('/example/d', [cb0, cb1], (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('the response will be sent by the next function ...')
  next()
}, (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello from D!')
})
```

From the above code, I'm passing an array of functions `[cb0, cb1]` and each function requires some `data` attribute of type `any` and additional parameters like `req`, `res` and `next`.

Earlier,I tried passing the data attribute like below format using `bind` concept.
`app.get('/example/d', [cb0.bind(data), cb1.bind(data)], (req, res, next)`

But if I use the `bind` concept, then how to pass the other required attributes (`req`, `res` and `next`)?
Is there any other way to pass all the parameters, including `data` without bind? or do we have any limitations in using the array of functions in the express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you've used [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) incorrectly (for how your functions are written): The first argument to bind is the value to use as `this` when calling the function; it's only the subsequent arguments that define arguments to give the function when called. So you'd want `cb0.bind(null, data)` rather than `cb0.bind(data)`.

> But if I use the `bind` concept, then how to pass the other required attributes (`req`, `res` and `next`)?

(They're arguments, not attributes.) Express does that when it calls your function. The arguments will follow the arguments you've "baked into" your functions via `bind`. Your functions are already set up correctly to handle that order (`data`, `req`, `res`, `next`), so with the change, you should be good to go.

So:

```
app.get('/example/d', [cb0.bind(null, data), cb1.bind(null, data)], (req, res, next) => {
    // ...
```

Just for clarity, here's an example of a function with data bound to it via `bind` being called with further arguments:

```js
function example(data, other) {
    console.log(`data = ${JSON.stringify(data)}, other = ${JSON.stringify(other)}`);
}

const ex = example.bind(null, "baked in arg");

// Emulating Express calling the middleware:
ex("passed arg");
```

---

Side note: You don't have to put your middleware functions in an array, express is happy with them as discrete arguments instead:

```
app.get('/example/d', cb0.bind(null, data), cb1.bind(null, data), (req, res, next) => {
    // ...
```

Either way is fine.